# Convert timestamp into one of custom Periods in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Say I defined 4 custom time periods for a day: 6am-12pm, 12pm-7pm, 7pm-00am, 00am-6am.
What is the clean way in pandas to convert a given timestamp to one of those Periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `numpy.searchsorted`:

```
>>> idx
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-26 22:20:34.580486, ..., 2014-08-29 05:20:34.581053]
Length: 12, Freq: None, Timezone: None
>>> idx.hour
array([22,  3,  8, 13, 18, 23,  4,  9, 14, 19,  0,  5], dtype=int32)

>>> p = np.array(['00am-06am', '06am-12pm', '12pm-07pm', '07pm-00am'])
>>> p[np.searchsorted([6, 12, 19, 24], idx.hour)]
array(['07pm-00am', '00am-06am', '06am-12pm', '12pm-07pm', '12pm-07pm',
       '07pm-00am', '00am-06am', '06am-12pm', '12pm-07pm', '12pm-07pm',
       '00am-06am', '00am-06am'], 
      dtype='<U9')
```

Comment: Ha, very clever, thanks! I'll mark that as the best answer if there won't be any special pandas-way to do that.